# Problem with method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation $ y''+2y'+y=2e^{-x} \ $ using **method of undetermined coefficient**.

**Answer:**

The trial solution is  $\ Y= Ae^{-x}+Bxe^{-x}+Cx^2e^{-x} \ $

Putting $ Y \ , Y', Y'' $ in the given equation and comparing we get

$ C=1, $

But $ A$ and $B$ becomes undetermined .

**Is my trial solution correct ?**

Answer (score 1):

In the case when the right part of the equation is of the form $P_n(x)e^{\alpha x}$, where $\alpha$ is equal to the root of multiplicity $m$ of the auxillary equation, the partial solution has the form
$x^m Q_n(x)e^{\alpha t}$, where $Q_n(x)$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $P_n(x)$.

The auxillary equation of this ode is 
$$
\lambda^2+2\lambda+1=0;
$$
it has one root $-1=\alpha$ of multiplicity $m=2$; the degree $n=0$; thus, the partial solution has the form 
$$
Y=Ax^2e^{-x}.
$$